# Redux state loss after refresh

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, react-redux

**components/Navbar.jsx**

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const {currentUser} = useSelector(state=>state.user)

    return(
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Search>
                    <Input placeholder="Search videos..." />
                    <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                </Search>
                {currentUser ? (
                    <User>
                        <VideoCallOutlinedIcon/>
                        <Avatar src={currentUser.img} />
                        {currentUser.user.name}
                    </User>
                ) : (
                    <Link to="/signin" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit"}}>
                        <Button> 
                            <AccountCircleOutlinedIcon />
                            SIGN IN 
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                )}
                
               
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

**pages/Signin.jsx**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleLogin = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(loginStart())
        try{
            const res = await axios.post("/auth/login",{
                email, password
            })
            console.log(res.data)
            dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
        } catch(err){
            dispatch(loginFailure())
        }
    }
```

**redux/userSlice.js**

```
const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    loading: false,
    error: false
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.loading = true
        },
        loginSuccess: (state,action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.currentUser = action.payload
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.error = true        
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.currentUser = null
            state.loading = false
            state.error = false
        }
    }
})
```

I am trying to login the user with redux state management and after refreshing the page the navbar could not maintain the logged in state correctly. May I ask how can I remain the state of logged in user unless the user logout to remove the state?

Comment: Consider using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score -1):

Maintaining a user's logged-in state in a Redux-managed application can be a challenge. When you refresh the page, the Redux store is reset, causing the logged-in state to be lost. To address this, you need to persist the user's authentication state across page reloads. Here are some strategies to accomplish this:

1. Use Local Storage | Cookies:

You can store the user's authentication token or session information in the browser's local storage or cookies. When the page is refreshed, you can check for this stored data and automatically log the user in if it's present. Be cautious about security when using this method.

2. Session Management on the Server:

If you are okay with a stateful server you can use session as an alternative.

3. Persist Redux State to Local Storage:

You can persist parts of your Redux store to local storage using libraries like redux-persist. By doing this, you can keep the user's authentication state even after a page refresh. Here's a basic example of how you might set up redux-persist:

```
// Install the necessary packages
npm install redux-persist

// In your Redux store configuration:
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  // Whitelist the parts of the store you want to persist, like authentication state.
  whitelist: ['auth'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);

const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

4. Auto-Login on Page Load:

When your app initializes, you can check if the user has a valid session or token (from local storage or cookies) and automatically log them in by dispatching the appropriate Redux action. For example:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) {
  // Dispatch a Redux action to log in the user with the token
  dispatch(loginUserWithToken(token));
}
```

Implementing one or a combination of these strategies ensures that your Redux-managed authentication state persists across page refreshes, providing a seamless experience for your users.